# Can I visit Israel if I have an Egyptian visa?

Tags: visas, israel, egypt, nepali-citizens

Can I visit Israel with a visitor visa issued by Egypt?

I am planning to visit Egypt for 3 weeks. Afterwards, I am planning to visit Israel. Is it possible to enter Israel with the Egyptian visa?

I am from Nepal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Israel is a different country.

To enter a different country, you'll need a visa for that country.

So no, if you have a visa for Egypt, it does not entitle you to visit Israel.  You'll need to obtain an Israeli visa for Nepalese citizens.